# Showing tooltip of QLineEdit upon focus in Qt

Tags: qt, focus, tooltip, qlineedit

I found that I can set a tooltip on a QLineEdit as such:

```
equation = new QLineEdit();
equation->setToolTip("Example: a*b+c+~c");
```

However, I would like the tooltip to be displayed when that QLineEdit is focused.
How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting there.
I've got this so far:

void EquationEditor::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
 QHelpEvent event(QEvent::ToolTip, this->pos(), this->pos());
 QApplication::sendEvent(this, &event);
 QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}

But I'm not sure how to set the last two parameters to QHelpEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by subclassing QLineEdit and overriding focusInEvent(...) as such:

```
void EquationEditor::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    QHelpEvent *event = new QHelpEvent(QEvent::ToolTip,
                                       QPoint(this->pos().x(), this->pos().y()),
                                       QPoint(QCursor::pos().x(), QCursor::pos().y()));  

    QApplication::postEvent(this, event);

    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have a look at the following example : [Tool Tips Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/widgets-tooltips.html)

You could show the tooltip when your LineEdit is getting the focus, maybe by connecting to this signal:

```
void QApplication::focusChanged ( QWidget * old, QWidget * now )   [signal]
```

There is also some pretty neat informations about Focus here : [QFocusEvent Class Reference](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfocusevent.html)

Hope it helps a bit !